# GetProcAddress return error code 127 in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-c++

I have a dll and header file. Now I am creating a console application using vs2015. and load this library. But while getting GetProcAddress of function. It is always returning NULL. Here is my code. 
Contents of header file (test.h) (This header file is only for your reference)

```
    #ifdef APPLYDLL_EXPORTS
#define APPLYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#ifdef BUILD_EXE
#define APPLYDLL_API
#else
#define APPLYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif

#include <string>
#include <winerror.h>

APPLYDLL_API HRESULT ApplySettings(std::string input);
```

Contents of console application (cpp file)

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//Define the function prototype
typedef HRESULT(CALLBACK* ApplySettings)(std::string);
int main()
{

    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("ApplyTool.dll"));
    if (NULL != hLib)
    {
        //Get pointer to our function using GetProcAddress:
        ApplySettings applySettings = (ApplySettings)GetProcAddress(hLib,"ApplySettings");


    DWORD errorcode=GetLastError(); //errorcode 127, Procedure not Found
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know, Where I am doing silly mistake.

Someone please help me.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: Most likely since you use C++ the name is mangled and you’ll have to find the actual name for it

Comment: I used dependecy walker to find the actual name of procedure. Other than any way.

Comment: You should use use dumpbin or similar tools to check export table of your library and determine whether it actually contains function named `ApplySettings`.

Comment: you can use next in function body `__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__ ));` - it print for you actual function name

Comment: or say `__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__ " -> " __FUNCSIG__ ));` for print actual function name (which need use in `GetProcAddress` with signature for self comfort)

Comment: also when you declare function in header file, which can be used from another project, need always direct set calling conventions. because different project can use different. say you declare `typedef HRESULT(CALLBACK* ApplySettings)(std::string);` when no `CALLBACK` in `APPLYDLL_API HRESULT ApplySettings(std::string input);`. are you use `CALLBACK` as default convention ?

Comment: I don't no the default convention in library. I also tried to print function name printf("%s \t %s", __FUNCDNAME__, __FUNCSIG__); it is printing main     int __cdecl main(void)

Comment: @CrazyCoder - `__FUNCDNAME__` this name of current function. need use it not from main but only from function which name you want get - are this not obvious ? and not `print` but exactly `__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__ ));`

Comment: and why you at all use `GetProcAddress` instead use generated lib file for static linking ?

Comment: Paste the result of `dumpbin /exports ApplyTool.dll | grep ApplySettings` into the question.

Comment: Function name was different.. This is like ?ApplySettings@@YAJV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z.

Comment: All that craziness (`#ifdef APPLYDLL_EXPORTS` and so on) is useless if you end up using dynamic loading. Just export via a definition file (extension .def)

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with CrazyCoder, check the DLL using Dependency Walker with that function name.

and try to change define as like below,

```
#define APPLYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
```

to

```
#define APPLYDLL_API extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )
```

Thanks, Jake.